# Python convert array of objects with k, v pairs into table

Tags: python, tabulate

I'm looking for way to convert the beneath list of dicts into a table.

From:

```
arr = [{'G': ["Apple", "Banana"]}, {'M': ["Orange", "Kiwi"]}, {'P': ["Orange"]}, {'MP': ["All"]}]
```

To:

| User | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| G | Apple, Banana |
| M | Orange, Kiwi |
| P | Orange |
| MP | All |

I'd also like to have the totals of each fruit detailed.

Beneath is my current solution, I'm making use of tabulate

```
table = tabulate(arr, tablefmt='html')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table = tabulate([ [ list(arr[i].keys())[0] , ','.join(arr[i].get(list(arr[i].keys())[0])) ] for i in range(len(arr)) ], tablefmt='html', headers=["User","Fruit"])
```

try this